# C++ systems not using "source files"

Tags: c++

In *The C++ Programming Language (4th edition), §15.1*, Stroustrup states:

> A file is the traditional unit
>   of storage (in a file system) and the traditional unit of compilation. There are systems that do not
>   store, compile, and present C++ programs to the programmer as sets of files.

Sadly, he doesn't give further information. Do you know **any example** of such systems?

**EDIT:**

I mean if you know any **actual** *free, commercial, opensource or whatever* C++ implementation that doesn't deal with files as we are accustomed to.

And I was wondering: Why do that systems exist? What's the point? What can be the advantages of such a design philosophy? What the drawbacks?

Comment: `$ generator args | compiler`

Comment: Let's assume `generator` is an application which generates some random programs and streams them to compiler directly or may be calls a compile function from other library. Program is generated and consumed by the compiler on the fly and no real **source** files are created that can be presented to the user.

Comment: @MohitJain Much better, thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, in the 1980s [IBM Visual Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_VisualAge) C++ stored the program source code (or perhaps a faithful representation of its [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) in some proprietary database. (It is rumored that header files also sit in some database at that time).

And current C++ compilers are often able to get the source code from a generated file, or even some pipe. For instance, on my Linux I could have a program `mygenerator`generating some C++ code on its *stdout* and invoke the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as:

```
mygenerator | g++ -x c++ /dev/stdin -Wall -O -o myprogram
```

However, *today*, most compilers are generally compiling source files and header files from some file system. Notice that an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) spend much more time in compilation proper than in disk IO, and you could use some [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system, so file read&write time is negligible when compiling C++ code (even parsing is often quicker than optimization & code generation).

<sup>So I know no C++ compiler used in 2015 which compiles and optimize source code outside of source *files*</sup>

Actually, generating C++ code is often a good idea (I'm doing it in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), which enables you to customize GCC), but usually you tweak your build procedure (e.g. your `Makefile`) to generate then compile some temporary C++ files. With current computers and operating systems and compilers (e.g. Linux & GCC) you could even generate some temporary C++ file, fork a compilation of it into a shared object plugin, and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) it.

A possible reason to store the source code in something better than a file -e.g. some database- would be to make an incremental compiler, which would recompile only one function if it was the only modification from the previous compilation. In practice, this is difficult to implement in *existing* compilers (it has been discussed, and sort-of prototyped, within the GCC community, but nothing stable came out of this). But C++ or C is not the best language for such an approach (Common Lisp is much better, and SBCL is able to compile and optimize in memory and incrementally), in particular because of its preprocessor.

BTW, [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) is able to compile C code sitting inside some `const char*` string in memory, but the performance of the generated machine code is bad (since `tcc` does not do any kind of serious optimizations, that current processors need so much).

Notice also that with [link time optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (e.g. compile *and link* with `g++ -flto -O2`) compilers are keeping some form of the AST (actually the [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) representation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) in object files.

Comment: Really a great answer

Answer (score 2):

C++ source code can be stored in a database in various ways.